# How to get number from string using Regex?

Tags: c#, regex, string, substring

I have the following string:

```
WOA: 1234-123 - Text Text Text Text
```

or

```
WOA 0123 Text Text Text
```

or

```
WOA 012345678 - Text Text Text
```

I need to get only Numbers from those strings (If number contains dashes inside I need those dashes too, but if dash at the end, I don't need it).
I know that I could do it using ASCII codes, but with Regex it will looks much better, but my knowledge in Regex very limited, so any help, please.

Comment: Show your best attempt.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Probably you're looking for this regex:

```
[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*
```

Comment: I would suggest to put in a `+` char instead of `?`: `\d+(-\d+)+`. Now it will also match on `123-456-78`. TS state explicitly multiple dashes: "If number contains dashes inside I need those dashes too"

Comment: Actually `[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)*` will be more accurate since not always hyphen will be there

Comment: You all should quit ninja editing your posts after I commented on it! :)

Comment: Deleted mine, because this is superior.

Comment: Thanks guys! It works, but who voted down my question? What's wrong with it?

Comment: You're welcome, glad that it worked out for you. Don't know who down-voted but I upvoted to nullify a down-vote.

Comment: @Bryuk I suspect your question was downvoted because you didn't show any attempts of your own. It is generally considered bad form on this site to omit your own attempts. I for one, however, consider a straightforward regex and a straightforward answers to be immensely useful, so I upvoted you just now, as well.